# How do I use other values in a vector in a std::transform?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, stl

Given the code below which just adds 1 to each element of a vector:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Create vector 1 - print it out
    std::vector<int> v1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (auto val : v1)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create vector 2 by a transform of vector 1 + 1
    std::vector<int> v2(v1.size());
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
        [](int val){ return val + 1; });

    // Print out vector 2
    for (auto val : v2)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;        
}
```

Instead of just adding 1 to each value I want to add the value of the previous element so that:

```
v[0] = v[0] (no previous value)
v[1] = v[1] + v[0]
v[2] = v[2] + v[1]
 etc...
```

So that I end up with:

```
1     = 1
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 2 = 5
4 + 3 = 7
etc...
```

Its a silly example - its not a maths puzzle or anything like that, I am just trying to figure out if I can use other values in my vector other then the one passed into the lambda function?

I am missing two bits of data in the lambda:

```cpp
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), [](int val){
            // What is the index of val?
            // What is the size of the vector v1?
            // How would I express this:
            if (INDEX_OF(val) > 0)
                return val + INDEX_OF(val - 1);
            else
                return val;
        });
```

I can pass v1 in by capture and use that to do some calculations, but not quite what I want since I don't know the index.

```cpp
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
        [&v1](int val){ return val + v1.size() - v1[0]; });
```

Maybe transform is not the tool for this job and I need to resort to iterator loop?:

```cpp
    std::vector<int> v2(v1.size());
    auto it2 = v2.begin();
    for (auto it1 = v1.begin(); it1 != v1.end(); it1++, it2++)
    {
        std::distance(v1.begin(), it1) == 0 ? *it2 = *it1 : *it2 = *it1 + *(it1 - 1);
    }
```

This works, but the point of my question is to know if it can be done with std::transform, or maybe some other algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add lambda capture to store the previous element's value.

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> v2(v1.size());
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
    [pv = 0](int val) mutable { int nv = pv + val; pv = val; return nv; });
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/85Mq2eZ3uESeUDUA)

PS: Captures with initializer was supported since C++14.

Comment: that is really great thanks - few questions: I can't seem to find a reference to `pv` - what is that? and why is it readonly (so you have to use mutable)? - are there other ways to index values? - can you do the same for the next value (i.e. index + 1)? - I assume not...

Comment: @code_fodder I suppose not either. We can't get index (and next value) in the algorithm like `std::transform`, we can only get the element in lambda. And we have to add `mutable` otherwise `operator()` of the lambda will be const-qualified and we can't modify the captured variable.

Comment: ah, I see. I am still slightly confused about the `pv` - where has that come from? - is it some sort of auto-deducted temporary? - I am trying to look that up (here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) but I can't quite find that part that allows this behaviour! - anyway marking up now as I have the answer

Comment: @code_fodder It just declares a data member named `pv` in the lambda closure type, then we can use it in the body of the lambda, i.e. in the `operator()`. In the page you linked you can refer to the paragraph starting from *A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable...*.

Comment: ahh, I almost guessed right - nice trick, thanks :)

Comment: `std::exchange` can make the lambda body simpler: `return val + std::exchange(pv, val);`

Answer (score 1):

@songyuanyao answers the question. This is similar solution to show how you can add a generic amount of memory for the previous values in your container.

```
#include <memory>

template<typename It1, typename It2>
void slide_transform(It1 first, It1 last, It2 write, size_t n = 1) {

    // a memory bank to store the previous values
    auto mem = std::make_unique<typename std::iterator_traits<It1>::value_type[]>(n);

    size_t rw = 0; // current position in memory

    std::transform(first, last, write,
        [&](const auto& val) {
            auto nv = val + mem[rw];
            mem[rw] = val;
            rw = (rw + 1) % n;
            return nv; 
        }
    );
}

// ...

// change 1 to a bigger value below to add earlier elements
slide_transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 1);
```

For this to be really useful one would probably want to be able to provide a user defined functor taking the previous value as a parameter and in that case I'd skip using `std::tranform` and do something like this:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename It1, typename It2, typename Func>
void slide_transform(It1 first, It1 last, It2 write, size_t n, Func func) {
    auto mem = std::make_unique<typename std::iterator_traits<It1>::value_type[]>(n);
    size_t rw = 0;
    for(;first != last; std::advance(first, 1)) {
        auto copy = *first;
        *write = func(mem[rw], *first);
        std::advance(write, 1);
        mem[rw] = copy;
        rw = (rw + 1) % n;
    }
}
// ...

slide_transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 1, [](auto prev_val, auto val) {
    return prev_val + val;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. This feels like its getting too complicated compared to what can be achieved in a simple 3-4 line iterator loop!, but the concepts here are interesting! - I assume also that this only really works for containers with contiguous memory? +1 for effort :)

Comment: @code_fodder Thanks! Yeah, it's for the more generic case so it becomes a little more complicated. It'll work for any container though since it's only using iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten a couple of answers pointing out the ability to use a capture to temporarily store the previous value for the next iteration.

For the job at hand, however, I'd personally take a slightly different approach. The overload of `std::transform` you're using takes one input range, applies an operation to each element, and pushes each result to an output range.

There is, however, another overload that takes two input ranges, applies an operation to combine them, and push the result to an output. That fits your requirement much better--it just happens that in your particular case the two input ranges overlap each other.

This does have a difficulty deal with the first element, that you want copied intact. We could create a proxy that yielded a phantom first element of 0, but for a first attempt, it's probably easier to just copy the first element, then use the algorithm for the remaining items.

If you honestly cared solely about the problem as you've posed it, capturing a reference and using that to temporarily store the value from one invocation to the next would probably be the more obvious choice.

The advantage of this is that it's easy to apply when (for example) you want to add each element to the element that was, say, 4 or 5 elements previous rather than the one immediately previous. For that more general form of the problem, I'd probably write code on this general order:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> v1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::vector<int> v2;

    int offset = 1;

    // copy the first N elements intact
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + offset, std::back_inserter(v2));

    // each remaining element gets added to the one N previous:
    std::transform(v1.begin()+offset, v1.end(), 
        v1.begin(), 
        std::back_inserter(v2), 
        [](auto a, auto b){ return a + b; });

    // show the result:
    std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

As it stands right now, this sets `offset` to `1`, which matches the question as you posed it. But if, for example, you wanted the first three items copied across and the remaining items each added to the element 3 before it in the input, you'd change `offset` to `3` (and leave the rest of the code intact).

Comment: This is a clever solution (+1) - as you say this works for the specific example I posted and also now with an offset - which is the cool part - but it does not allow us to access items infront - I suppose we could come up with a similar solution for the negative offset, but this starts to become very convoluted - I think we can really beat the simple iterator loop in this case :)

Comment: @code_fodder: A negative vs. positive offset doesn't really mean much. If you want the items in the other direction, you simply reverse how you use them inside the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of just adding 1 to each value I want to add the value of the previous element.

You exactly describe the `partial_sum` function from the standard library. You can pass as parameters user defined functions too. To know more about it click [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/partial_sum/).

Comment: No, OP only wants to add two adjacent elements at a time. That is, for the input `std::vector<int> v1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, the result should be `{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}`, not `{1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45}`.

Comment: @EloyPérezTorres that's an interesting algorithm, thankyou : ) although I really just wanted to know if I can access other elements in the vector